# How to test if Enum value is in EnumSet using JPQL

Tags: java, enums, jpql

I have a property as follows:

```
@Entity
class Project implements Serializable {
  @Convert(converter = TypeFlattener.class)
  @Column(name = "assignable_types")
  private EnumSet<Type> assignableTypes;
```

The point of the `TypeFlattener` is that I want to avoid normalization for a simple list, so basically it converts the `EnumSet` to/from a simple String with comma separated values matching the `Enum.name()`

Now the question is how can I filter only Projects that have the a specific Type in assignableTypes?

My best approach would be something like that:

```
@NamedQuery(
  name="Project.findByType", 
  query="SELECT p FROM Project p WHERE :t IN p.assignableTypes"
)
```

What do I pass in for `:t`? The String version as follows? Can I even do this?

```
q.setParameter("id", "MAJOR");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The converter does not matter here as he only affects the database representation. The below query using [MEMBER OF](https://docs.oracle.com/html/E13946_01/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_collection_member) should work.

```
TypedQuery<Project> query = em.createQuery(
    "SELECT p FROM Project p WHERE :type MEMBER OF p.assignableTypes", Project.class);
query.setParameter("type", Type.ONE);
List<Project> resultMemberOf = query.getResultList();
```

Comment: That was sweet and short. Thanks.